# How to use dropna to drop columns on a subset of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use Pandas' `dropna` function on `axis=1` to drop columns, but only on a subset of columns with some `thresh` set. More specifically, I want to pass an argument on which columns to ignore in the `dropna` operation. How can I do this? Below is an example of what I've tried.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'building': ['bul2', 'bul2', 'cap1', 'cap1'],
    'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01'],
    'rate1': [301, np.nan, 250, 276],
    'rate2': [250, 300, np.nan, np.nan],
    'rate3': [230, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
    'rate4': [230, np.nan, 245, np.nan], 
})

# Only retain columns with more than 3 non-missing values
df.dropna(1, thresh=3)
    building    date    rate1
0   bul2    2019-01-01  301.0
1   bul2    2019-02-01  NaN
2   cap1    2019-01-01  250.0
3   cap1    2019-02-01  276.0

# Try to do the same but only apply dropna to the subset of [building, date, rate1, and rate2],
# (meaning do NOT drop rate3 and rate4)
df.dropna(1, thresh=3, subset=['building', 'date', 'rate1', 'rate2'])
KeyError: ['building', 'date', 'rate1', 'rate2']
```

Comment: When dropna with axis=1 your subset is which rows to consider for your threshold, so your subset is a group if row index not column headers.  If you only want to drop centain columns based on threshold, then you need to filter your dataframe first then dropna and add back in the remaining columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# Desired subset of columns against which to apply `dropna`.
cols = ['building', 'date', 'rate1', 'rate2']

# Apply `dropna` and see which columns remain.
filtered_cols = df.loc[:, cols].dropna(axis=1, thresh=3).columns

# Use a conditional list comprehension to determine which columns were dropped.
dropped_cols = [col for col in cols if col not in filtered_cols]

# Use a conditional list comprehension to display all columns other than those that were dropped.
new_cols = [col for col in df if col not in dropped_cols]
>>> df[new_cols]
  building        date  rate1  rate3  rate4
0     bul2  2019-01-01  301.0  230.0  230.0
1     bul2  2019-02-01    NaN    NaN    NaN
2     cap1  2019-01-01  250.0    NaN  245.0
3     cap1  2019-02-01  276.0    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it easiest to first count the number of not null values in each column and then apply your criteria:

```py
# Count not null values in each column
notnulls = df.notnull().sum()
# Find columns with >3 not null values
notnull_cols = notnulls[notnulls>3].index
# Subset df to these columns
df[notnull_cols]
```

Comment: To get the op's desired result,  it should be `notnulls = df[['building', 'date', 'rate1', 'rate2']].notnull().sum()`