# Why Pandas dropna function with axis=1 doesn't mean to drop columns when specified a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas

The dropna function is supposed to drop columns if axis=1 and rows if axis=0 and it does work like this If I don't add subset parameters.

However when I want to apply drop only to certain columns by adding subset means to a group of column headers, it gives error.

I've read in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546864/how-to-use-dropna-to-drop-columns-on-a-subset-of-columns-in-pandas?newreg=652f29cbc89040cbb71758b79974df49) that this is because Pandas is expecting to receive subset to be rows when axis=1. But that doesn't make sense to me.

Can anyone help explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better off making a new dataframe only including what you do want.

Comment: Yes, I did do that and was able to get what I want. But I wanted to know why axis=1 and subset of columns are not compatible.

Comment: Post your code. It should work fine unless index or column names don't match. Did you inplace=True or reassign the dataframe to a new variable?